# EJB container swallows exception

Tags: java, eclipse, jsf, ejb-3.0, glassfish-3

I've recently started using EJB's for an application I'm developing, however, I'm encountering problems with the exception handling. In short, my businesslayer is throwing customized exceptions, but they are never caught in the web-layer.

To start with, this is the software I'm using:

- IDE: Eclipse Kepler
- Java version: 1.7
- Application server: Glassfish 3.1.2
- JSF 2.1

My code:

Remote interface:

```
@Remote
public interface IUserService {

public UserRequest createAccount(<some string parameters>) throws ApplicationException;
}
```

Stateless session bean:

```
@Stateless
public class UserServiceImpl implements IUserService {

@Override
@Interceptors({ LoggingInterceptor.class, CheckParametersInterceptor.class })
public UserRequest createAccount(<some string parameters>) throws ApplicationException {

    throw new ApplicationException("Exception thrown");

    return null;
}

}
```

JSF managed bean:

```
public class CreateAccountBean {

@EJB
IUserService userService;

public CreateAccountBean() {

}

public String confirmCreate() {

    try {
        userService.createAccount(<some string values>);
    } catch (ApplicationException e) {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, e.getMessage(), e.getMsgDetail()));
    }

    return "create_succeeded";
}
}
```

When I do a call to the managedbean "CreateAccountBean" an exception is thrown by the businesslayer (in UserServiceImpl), however, when I debug through my code, I never arrive in the catch clause of the the calling method. I've not been able to find a solution, until I tried removing the @EJB annotations and replaced them with a call to the constructor. At that point, the exception is in fact caught in the web layer by the managed bean, but that doesn't solve my problem, because I'm not using EJB's anymore at that point, but because this happens I'm assuming that it's the EJB container that is swallowing the exceptions.

By the way, the exceptions also appear in my server logs (which is proof that they are in fact thrown)

As you can see from my code, I'm also using interceptors to handle logging and parameter validation. I don't think they're causing the problems, but I could be wrong on this...

It seems that I'm missing something or doing something wrong, but I don't know what, so if anybody could help me out on this, that would be great!

Comment: What kind of exception is your `ApplicationException`? Is it a RuntimeException? Is it annotated with `javax.ejb.ApplicationException`?

Comment: It's name isn't actually ApplicationException, I just renamed it to be more clear. It extends the class Exception, so it's a checked exception.

Comment: What does the exception handling look like in the interceptors?

Comment: I don't do exception handling in the interceptors... only parameter validation and logging